# i want results output how many str2 matches string values matching with str1. Required code for how many are true and false like total marks

Tags: javascript

I want results output how many `str2` matches string values matching with `str1`.  Required code for how many are `true` and `false` like total marks.

```
function myFunction() {
    var str1 = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
    var str2 = ["world", "Hello", "welcome", "jurrassic"];
    var text = "";
    for (i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
      text += str1.includes(str2[i]) + "<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: Not able to get what you are asking..

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the count of words, from the words array, occurring in the first string

```js
var str1 = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var str2 = ["world", "Hello", "welcome", "jurrassic"];

var count = str2.reduce((count, item) => count + (str1.includes(item) ? 1 : 0), 0);

console.log("Count: ", count);
```